# How to modify a value for a parameter in a query string and return the new string?

Tags: python

If I have

`qs = 'search=One+two+three&product=apple'`

How do I add  `'+four'` to search param? `qs` can have an unknown number of parameters.

Comment: The duplicate covers the second half of this problem (reassembling into a string), but the question shows the first half. And the answers show an example of parsing and reassembling.

Comment: The duplicate is somewhat misleading, and some digging is required to actually get the desired solution. OP, see [`urllib.parse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs).

Comment: new = qs [:qs.index ("&")] + "+four" + qs [qs.index ("&"):]